# React Native watchPosition not updating even after moving roughly 370m (android)

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I'm currently trying to get the Android app to determine my position, and then upload the latitude and longitude to firebase every 10 seconds. The upload seems fine at the moment, but the navigator.geolocation.watchPosition doesn't seem to update even after moving 370m even though its supposed to update every 10m.

I've tried testing both in an emulator by changing the latitude and longitude, and also in real life by cycling 370 metres.

Oh and yes, I've included permissions for FINE location in the android manifest. I've also tried testing to see if the geolocation works at all, and it seems to update if I emulate myself in London and then next in Oxford. So no problem in detecting massive changes in location, but not if the location difference is only 370m, say one end of a road to another.

Really would appreciate any help!. Thanks in advance!

```
 import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

let myDatas={
  timestamp:[],
  longitude:[],
  latitude:[],
};

export default class GeoLocation extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      timestamp: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
var watchPositionID;


    watchPositionID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        let now = new Date()
        myDatas.longitude.push(position.coords.longitude);
        myDatas.latitude.push(position.coords.latitude);
        myDatas.timestamp.push(now);
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          timestamp: now,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({error:error.message}),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 10},
      );


this.uploadTimer=setInterval(
  ()=>{
    uploadData(myDatas);
    myDatas={
      timestamp:[],
      longitude:[],
      latitude:[],
    };
  },10000
  )

}

componentWillUnmount() {
  navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchPositionID);
  this.uploadTimer && clearInterval(this.uploadTimer);
  this.timerpos && clearInterval(this.timerpos);
}



render() {
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
    <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
    </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you move around and manually fetch updates with getCurrentPosition (like with a button)?

Comment: @Carter Mah - have you found a solution? I'm testing on iOS and for me the location updates fine in the simulator, but not on a real device.